# BigQuery Transfer API: updating the AdWords transfer config is not working through projects.locations.transferConfig.patch

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, data-transfer-objects

I am trying to disable the AdWords transfer object through API (projects.locations.transferConfig.patch)
Ref: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/patch?apix=true

Request Body:

> {   "name":
>   "projects/digital-hall-119520/locations/us/transferConfigs/5abc469c-0000-2340-9419-f403045efe74",
>   "destinationDatasetId": "Test_Backfill",   "displayName":
>   "PatchTransferNew",   "dataSourceId": "adwords",   "params": {
>       "customer_id": "7875544940"   },   "schedule": "every 24 hours",   "dataRefreshWindowDays": 2,   "disabled": false }

Getting the below error even I give the valid request body. I tried many times, got the same error.

> {   "error": {
>       "code": 400,
>       "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
>       "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"   } }

Answer (score 0):

You need to set updateMask for fields you want to update and then in request body just specify these fields. E.g.

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/v1/<RESOURCE_NAME>?updateMask=disabled' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"disabled":true}' \
  --compressed
```

In API Explorer:
[image]